# PHP error when using ucfirst() with variables

Tags: php, variables, fatal-error, ucfirst

Im trying to display a country name from a database with first letter capitalised. For instance, if the country was Brazil, the database has it as 'brazil', and I would like it to be 'Brazil'.

This is the code I have tried:

`ucfirst($name) = $country_aa['name'];`

And this is the fatal error returned:

`Can't use function return value in write context`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing to a variable but to a result of a function call. It should be this instead:

```
$name = ucfirst($country_aa['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax

ucfirst(string)

```
$country_name = ucfirst($country_aa['name']);
```